# file download permission denied to read the file

Tags: php, apache, download, permissions

I am using php readfile function to ignore giving full direct url of the file on server. However it displays error only instead of downloading the file, stating `failed to open stream: No such file or directory in` However the file is in the specified directory.

The file I am trying to download is uploaded by user (i.e. httpd process i think, which will be owner). However the following code says unable to open the file -

```
$full_path = $row['full_path'];
            $file_name = $row['file_path'];
            header("Pragma: public");
            header("Expires: 0");
            header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
            header('Content-Type: application/pdf');
            header("Content-Type: application/force-download");
            header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"".$file_name."\"");                 

            readfile($full_path);
```

Default permissions set for the directory as 755 and the file which I am downloading also shows permissions as 755. i am unable to understand whats the issue here.

EDIT: Server is hostgator.

EDIT: header("Location: $full_path") works fine, so I don't think its related to path.

EDIT: `$full_path` looks like - `uploads/abc.pdf` while `$file_path` looks like `abc.pdf`

File structure:

```
--root
  downloader.php
      ---uploads
         abc.pdf
```

Comment: Well, it doesn't say it cannot find the file for fun. There's probably something wrong with the paths used. Please show us what's in `$row['full_path'];`, `$row['file_path']`, etc.

Comment: 755 on files makes them executables. Try changing it to 644.

Comment: @Oldskool I have edited the question to include the details you asked. Can you please have a look again...Thanks

Comment: @Fred-ii- Yeah I just made them temporarily

Comment: @codeomnitrix Uhm, if it works in a header it means it's an URL, not a path. That would only work if allow_url_fopen is enabled in php.ini. And also only if it's the full URL including `http://www.domain.com/`.

Comment: Please post examples for the `$full_path` and your file system layout.

Comment: @arkascha Updated the details of the variable

Comment: so what happens if you `/uploads/abc.pdf` back to the root?

Comment: With "your file system layout" I mean the location of the file in your local file system, the location of the executed script, so how they relate to each other. I suspect that your script needs a different path to reach the file than what you expect.

Comment: @arkascha the script in the root folder while the abc.pdf in sub folder. I doubt if I get your comment fully

Comment: What's your current working directory at that point? Maybe some part of your scripts change it for some conversion or similar?

Comment: And a general remark: you should move that `uploads` folder to _not_ be located within the file tree you publish via your http server. A question of security, so that you can be certain that no one can bypass your `download.php` script. When doing so you probably also want to change the `uploads/` part of the "full path" to an absolute path that is stored somewhere in a configuration file to keep your code portable to different systems.

Comment: what does `var_dump();` reveal? make sure there's no whitespace introduced anywhere also. I'm kind of baffled at this point. maybe error reporting too http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php and/or could be something with the db code.

Comment: WTF, there was a whitespace at the end in the string. I am really sorry for this, I never checked for that. Thanks to all of you guys, I will close the question

Comment: There's something that's unclear and you may have made a typo in your question. You say *"$full_path looks like - uploads/abc.pdf while $file_path looks like abc.pdf"* - Yet I don't see `$file_path` defined here, but `$file_name`. Plus, you sure you're not outside a loop for `$row` here? As I said, see what `var_dump()` reveals and what error reporting says

Comment: @codeomnitrix ah so [my comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36579944/file-download-permission-denied-to-read-the-file#comment60759602_36579944) about checking for whitespace helped then. using `trim()` would have fixed that in a jiffy. Worthy of an answer on my part, yes/no? ;-) you're welcome though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seeing that my comments to the OP did solve this one...

Me:

> *"what does var_dump(); reveal? make sure there's no whitespace introduced anywhere also. I'm kind of baffled at this point. Fred -ii-"*

OP:

> *"WTF, there was a whitespace at the end in the string. I am really sorry for this, I never checked for that. Thanks to all of you guys... – codeomnitrix"*

Me:

> *`trim()` would have fixed that in a jiffy*

Consult: http://php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php

Comment: Thanks man, I wouldn't have looked at the white space thing if you didn't point out. Thanks a lot

Comment: @codeomnitrix You're most welcome. Seeing your code checked out, that was the only thing I thought would have caused all this. Glad to know this one was solved, *cheers*.